# howto read extract files in web server j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, inputstream

It is possible from a .zip file in a servlet, unzip and read the contents of your files without having to save it to your hard drive.

In the method I can ller unzip the name of the extracted files but ????? I want to read the files extracted

```
public void unZip2(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, InputStream in)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

     try {

            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));

            ZipEntry entry;
            ZipEntry ze = null;

            while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {


              ??????????????

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
            // throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    //unZip(request, response);

ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload();
// set the file size limit
fileUpload.setSizeMax(MAX_SIZE_LIMIT);

response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        FileItemIterator iterator = fileUpload.getItemIterator(request);
        out.println("dfsdfsdf"+iterator.hasNext());

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
            InputStream mathMLContent = item.openStream();

            if (item.isFormField()) {
                out.println("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName());
            } else {
                String fileName = item.getName();
                String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                String contentType = item.getContentType();

                InputStream oInputStream  = item.openStream();
                unZip2(request,response,oInputStream);
                out.println("fileName:" + fileName );
                out.println("fieldName:"+ fieldName );
                out.println("contentType:"+contentType);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace ?????????????

```
while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                            int len;
                            while ((len = zis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                baos.write(buf, 0, len);
                            }

                            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();      

                          String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                          System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>"+str);
                      }
```